# Where do highschool algebra polynomials and Trigonometry fall in the Mathematics Subject Classification (MSC)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

The division "11 - Number Theory" mentions Polynomials in its classification "11CXX Polynomials and Matrices". They are also acknowledged in "12 Field Theory and Polynomials". Where do these polynomials belong to?

The closest thing I could find for Trigonometry is "11L03 Trigonometric and exponential sums, general" in "11Lxx Exponential sums and character sums" but it doesn't ring a bell. Where does Trigonometry fall?